# How to make details of an event private in Sharepoint Calendar

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, calendar

I'm developing a booking system, where users can create their bookings on a Sharepoint Calendar by adding new items.

What I want is that users should be able to see other existing events -or that the time slot of other events is unavailable-, but they shouldn't be able to see details of other events (who created it, other metadata etc.)

How can I achieve it best? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to disable the hyperlink.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {      
     setInterval(function (){
        $(".ms-acal-item").bind("click dblclick", function () {
            return false;
        });
        $(".ms-acal-item a").bind("click dblclick", function () {
            return false;
        });

        $(".ms-acal-item a").each(function(){
            $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
        });     
    },1000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to avoid Double Bookings?
With JavaScript and jQuery you can query your calendar for conflicting events
[image: Events and Possible Overlap Situations]

Based on this image, the 'Event' needs a query that finds Events A,B,E and F (C and D don't overlap 'Event'). To determine if they are conflicts.

- Start of Other Events are with the Start and End of this Event
- End of Other Events are with the Start and End of this Event
- Start of Other Events is less the Start of this Event and End of Other Events is greater then the End of this Event

To the code:

`sd = CurrentEventStart.toISOString(), ed = CurrentEventEnd.toISOString();`

Start Dates With-in: (note use of sd and ed)

`(StartDate+ge+datetime'"+sd+"'+and+StartDate+le+datetime'"+ed+"')+or+`

End Dates With-in: (note use of sd and ed)

`(OData__EndDate+ge+datetime'"+sd+"'+and+OData__EndDate+le+datetime'"+ed+"')+or+`

Overlapping Events: (Starts prior and Ends after) 'Event B' in image

`(StartDate+le+datetime'"+sd+"'+and+OData__EndDate+ge+datetime'"+ed+"')`

Last you will want to exclude the current event (if it is an edit form):

`+and+ID+ne+'CurrentEventID'`

In the return/success callback you can process each Event to determine if it is a conflict
If you have multiple resources/multiple users assigned.

You could let the user know who isn't availible of or even remove them as options so they can't be double booked.